# How to remove asterisk from this spin syntax code?

Tags: regex

here is my code it is a text spinner (synonym)

```
public function fetchContent($keyword)
{
    $customContent = $this->getOption('custom_content_text');

    $this->_setHttpStatusCode(200);

    if (!$customContent)
    {
        $this->_setContentStatus(self::CONTENT_STATUS_NO_RESULTS);
        return false;
    }

    if (preg_match_all('/({\*)(.*?)(\*})/', $customContent, $result))
    {
        if (is_array($result[0]))
        {
            foreach ($result[0] as $index => $group_string)
            {
                //replace the first or next pattern match with a replaceable token
                $customContent = preg_replace('/(\{\*)(.*?)(\*\})/', '{#'.$index.'#}', $customContent, 1);

                $words = explode('|', $result[2][$index]);

                //clean and trim all words
                $finalPhrase = array();
                foreach ($words as $word)
                {
                    if (preg_match('/\S/', $word))
                    {
                        $word = preg_replace('/{%keyword%}/i', $keyword, $word);
                        $finalPhrase[] = trim($word);
                    }
                }

                $finalPhrase = $finalPhrase[rand(0, count($finalPhrase) - 1)];

                //now inject it back to where the token was
                $customContent = str_ireplace('{#' . $index . '#}', $finalPhrase,    $customContent);
            }

            $this->_setContentStatus(self::CONTENT_STATUS_PASSED);
        }
    }

    return $customContent;
}
}
```

there is regex that request bracket like this

```
   {*spin1|spin2|spin3*}
```

here is the regex from the snippet above

```
   if (preg_match_all('/({\*)(.*?)(\*})/', $customContent, $result))

   $customContent = preg_replace('/(\{\*)(.*?)(\*\})/', '{#'.$index.'#}', $customContent, 1);
```

i would like to remove the * to format allow just {spin1|spin2|spin3} wich is more compatible with most spinner ,

i tried with some regex that i find online 
i tried to remove the * from both regex without result

thanks you very much for your help

Comment: You could try `preg_replace('/{\*(.*?)\*}/', '{#$1#}', $customContent);`

Comment: Remove `\*` instead of just `*`

Comment: thx you Lucas your trick did the work :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\*` instead of just `*` –  Lucas Trzesniewski